# How to get content of objectId in an Array - Mongoose / NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I would like to get an array/object of my tags with the content of my objectId (found by user id).

**userModel**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    pseudo : { type : String },
    fullname : { type : String },
    password : { type : String },
    email : { type : String },
    //tags : { type : Array },
    tags : [
        {
            objectId : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'tag'},
            completed : { type : Boolean }
        }
    ],
    dateCreation : { type : Date, default : Date.now }
});
```

**tagModel**

```
var tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : { type : String },
  alias : { type : String },
  description : { type : String },
  dateCreation : { type : Date, default : Date.now }
});
```

**mongoose request**

```
userModel.find({ _id : req.session.passport.user._id }).select('tags').populate('objectId', 'name alias').lean().exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

**console.log**

```
[
    {
        "_id":"538efe4a3bb9d97018b90ee4",
        "tags":[
                   {
                    "objectId":"538f25f7f4d621281b7376e9", 
                    "completed":false, 
                    "_id":"538f25f7f4d621281b7376ea"
                   }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to get content of objectId :/ Like 'name', 'alias'...

I know that I can write two request to get content, but it's not optimized :/

Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full, dot-notation path of the field to populate in your `populate` call:

```
userModel.find({ _id : req.session.passport.user._id })
    .select('tags')
    .populate('tags.objectId', 'name alias')
    .lean()
    .exec(function (err, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
);
```

Comment: Nice!
I was blocked since 4 hours. Thank you very much